# unsetting objects in an array based on a bool method

Tags: php

I'm trying to filter an array of objects implementing a specific interface (which simply defines the `isComplete(): bool` method) based on the result of that method. `array_filter` doesn't work because it can't call a method on each object to determine whether to filter it (or can it?). I've tried writing a function that takes the splatted array as an argument by reference, this doesn't work either:

```
function skipIncomplete(CompletableObjectInterface &...$objects): array {
    $skipped = [];
    foreach ($objects as $index => $item) {
        if (!$item->isComplete()) {
            $skipped[] = $item->id ?? $index;
            unset($objects[$index]);
        }
    }
    return $skipped;
}
```

The original elements passed in simply don't end up getting unset.

I'm looking for a way that doesn't include creating an entirely new Collection class to hold my CompletableObjects for complexity reasons. I really want to keep the type hint so no one can pass in a generic array, causing runtime errors when the function tries to call `$item->isComplete`.

Is there any way I can achieve this in PHP 7.3.15?

Comment: Btw, I'm aware I can just `return [$skipped, $objects]`, but this feels inelegant and also requires refactoring the places that call this function.

Comment: What is the problem with the `array_filter()` function? What are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: Objects that don't appear to die: https://3v4l.org/nIfhI .  You kill the reference not the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a filter, please comment as to what is wrong with this type of approach:

```
<?php

interface CompletableObjectInterface {
    public function isComplete() : bool;
}
class Foo implements CompletableObjectInterface
{
    public function isComplete() : bool
    {
        return false;
    }
}
class Bar implements CompletableObjectInterface
{
    public function isComplete() : bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$bar = new Bar;

$incomplete = array_filter([$foo, $bar], function($obj) { return !$obj->isComplete();});
var_dump($incomplete);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Foo)#1 (0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: You can type hint that anoymous function with your interface if you want a guard.

Comment: I think my mind blanked, I somehow didn't realize I could just use an anonymous function as array_filter's callback...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got a bit hung up on a wrong understanding of the [... syntax for a variable number of arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new).

You are passing in one array, and the `$objects` parameter will therefore contain that array in the first index, i.e. in `$objects[0]`.

So in theory you could just change your line

```
unset($objects[$index]);
```

to

```
unset($objects[0][$index]);
```

However, I do not really see why the variable number of arguments syntax is used at all, since you apparently are just expecting one array of values (objects in this case) as an argument to the function. Therefore I'd recommend you just remove the `...` from the argument list and your solution does what you wanted.

Alternatively you can of course add an outer foreach-loop and iterate over all passed "arrays of objects", if that is an use case for you.

Comment: The `...` is necessary in this implementation in order to type hint the `CompletableObjectInterface`. Without this workaround, I can only type hint `array` and others can pass any array to the function, whether or not the array elements satisfy the interface, which means I'd have to add additional type checks inside the function to prevent nasty runtime errors. I do pass the array as `skipIncomplete(...$array)`, so that part actually works correctly, it's just the reference that doesn't work the way I need it to.